# Powershell regex for a file path

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to find out regex for `\\mudit.bah.*[ps1|bat]` that means path can be like `\\mudit.bah.xyz123.ps1` or `\\mudit.bah.xyz123.bat` `xyz123` can be anything.
I am using https://rextester.com/tester and trying it however I am able to do till `\\{2}mudit.bah.`. I am not sure how what to use for `*` which can be multiple character with `.(dots)` or without `.(dots)`.
Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Comment: For specifying whether to match `ps1` or `bat` you need to write `(ps1|bat)` instead of it in square brackets which define character set.

Comment: Thanks! Anything for `*` which can be any `string` or `number` or `-` or `_`

Comment: Try `^\\{2}mudit\.bah\..*(?:ps1|bat)$`, see see [this demo](https://rextester.com/tester/HDIA91126). If you mean there can only be letters, digits, `-` or `_`, use ``^\\{2}mudit\.bah\.[\w-]*(?:ps1|bat)$``. To only match a part without dots, use `^\\{2}mudit\.bah\.[^.]*\.(?:ps1|bat)$` ([demo](https://rextester.com/tester/GFDJKL21527))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `[ps1|bat]` matches a single char, `p`, `s`, `1`, `b`, `a` or `t`. To make a group that matches either `ps1` or `bat`, you need a grouping construct, `(ps1|bat)` or  `(?:ps1|bat)` (non-capturing group).

To match any char as many times as possible other than newline, you may use `.*`. To restrict it to any char but a dot, use a negated character class, `[^.]`. Notet that `[^.]*` will match 0 or more chars other than a dot while `[^.]+` will match 1 or more.

Hence, you may use this regex to allow any chars between  `\\mudit.bah.` and `ps1` or `bat`:

```
^\\{2}mudit\.bah\..*\.(?:ps1|bat)$
```

Or, with the restriction to only one no-dot part in between them:

```
^\\{2}mudit\.bah\.[^.]*\.(?:ps1|bat)$
```

See [the regex demo](https://rextester.com/tester/GFDJKL21527).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\\{2}` - two backslashes
- `mudit\.bah\.` - a `mudit.bah.` substring
- `[^.]+\.` - any 1+ chars other than `.` and then a dot
- `(?:ps1|bat)` - either `ps1` or `bat`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

for a regex match like you requested use:

^mudit.bah.*.(ps1|bat)

```
get-childitem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^mudit\.bah.*.(ps1|bat)"}
```

This will get the files that start with mudit.bah. and end in ps1 or bat.  The .* after 'bah' will match any character, including numbers and symbols.

To do this without regex:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {($_.Name -like ("mudit.bah." + "*" + ".ps1")) -or ($_.Name -like ("mudit.bah." + "*" + ".bat"))}
```